# How can I add chapters to a mp4 file using bash script and ffmpeg

Tags: bash, shell, ffmpeg

I'm trying to add chapters to an mp4 file using bash and ffmpeg.  The chapters are located in a file called `chapters.txt`.  When the bash script is run which is called `add_chapters.sh` it reads the `chapters.txt` file and creates a file called `chapters.ffmetadata`.  The issue is that the `START` and `END` times in the file `chapters.ffmetadata` aren't being created correctly.  How can I fix this?

1. I have a file called `chapters.txt` that has the chapters in it.

   ```
   00:00:00=Intro
   00:02:12=What are selections
   00:03:19=Booleans
   ```
2. The bash file I run is `add_chapters.sh`

   The code in it is:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash

   input_file="chapters.txt"
   output_file="chapters.ffmetadata"

   # Create the FFmetadata chapter file
   echo ";FFMETADATA1" > "$output_file"

   previous_seconds=0

   while IFS="=" read -r timestamp chapter_name; do
       # Convert start time to seconds
       seconds=$(date -u -d "1970-01-01 $timestamp" +"%s")

       # Calculate the end time (previous chapter's start time)
       end_seconds=$previous_seconds

       # Update previous_seconds for the next iteration
       previous_seconds=$seconds

       echo "[CHAPTER]" >> "$output_file"
       echo "TIMEBASE=1/1000" >> "$output_file"
       echo "START=${end_seconds}000" >> "$output_file"
       echo "END=${seconds}000" >> "$output_file"
       echo "title=$chapter_name" >> "$output_file"
   done < "$input_file"

   echo "Chapter file '$output_file' created successfully."

   # Run FFmpeg to add chapters to the video
   ffmpeg -i input_video.mp4 -i chapters.ffmetadata -map_metadata 1 -c:v copy -c:a copy -y output_video.mp4
   ```
3. It creates a file called `chapters.ffmetadata`

   ```
   ;FFMETADATA1
   [CHAPTER]
   TIMEBASE=1/1000
   START=0000
   END=0000
   title=Intro
   [CHAPTER]
   TIMEBASE=1/1000
   START=0000
   END=132000
   title=What are selections
   [CHAPTER]
   TIMEBASE=1/1000
   START=132000
   END=199000
   title=Booleans
   [CHAPTER]
   TIMEBASE=1/1000
   START=199000
   END=0000
   title=
   ```

   The `START` and `END` times aren't being calculated correctly. How can I fix this?

---

#### UPDATE #1

I'm almost there thanks to **@Freeman** code / answer.

The issues in the generated
`chapters.ffmetadata` file are just.

1. The first `START=` and `END=` are `0000`
2. The **Intro** Chapter doesn't show up (most likely caused by the first `START=` and `END=` being `0000`)
3. The Chapters seem to be shifted down by one timecode line (most likely caused by the first `START=` and `END=` being `0000`)

   ;FFMETADATA1
   [CHAPTER]
   TIMEBASE=1/1000
   START=0000
   END=0000
   title=Intro
   [CHAPTER]
   TIMEBASE=1/1000
   START=0000
   END=132000
   title=What are selections?
   [CHAPTER]
   TIMEBASE=1/1000
   START=132000
   END=199000
   title=Booleans
   [CHAPTER]
   TIMEBASE=1/1000
   START=199000
   END=0000
   title=
   [CHAPTER]
   TIMEBASE=1/1000
   START=0000
   END=4459000
   title=

---

#### UPDATE #2

Strange; I tried the changes @Freeman suggested but an error comes up now.

**Chapter end time 0 before start 199000
chapters.ffmetadata: Cannot allocate memory**

```
;FFMETADATA1
[CHAPTER]
TIMEBASE=1/1000
START=0000
END=0000
title=Intro
[CHAPTER]
TIMEBASE=1/1000
START=0000
END=132000
title=What are selections?
[CHAPTER]
TIMEBASE=1/1000
START=132000
END=199000
title=Booleans
[CHAPTER]
TIMEBASE=1/1000
START=199000
END=0000
title=
[CHAPTER]
TIMEBASE=1/1000
START=0000
END=4459000
title=
```

---

#### UPDATE #3 using his awk changes

```
;FFMETADATA1
[CHAPTER]
TIMEBASE=1/1000
START=0000
END=0000
title=Intro
[CHAPTER]
TIMEBASE=1/1000
START=0000
END=132000
title=What are selections?
[CHAPTER]
TIMEBASE=1/1000
START=132000
END=199000
title=Booleans
[CHAPTER]
TIMEBASE=1/1000
START=199000
END=0000
title=
```

Comment: Please no cross-posting: https://askubuntu.com/q/1486030/336375

Comment: you can't output your first chapter block until you've read the 2nd line of data, so you will then have the END time for the first block. Usually people store and swap to variables name like prev_chap_start, prev_chap_end, etc. I can get messy (-;. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The end time of each chapter is the start time of the *next* chapter. You thus have to know the start time for the next chapter (or, for the last chapter, the end of the file) before you can output it.

Using the command from https://superuser.com/a/945604  to get the total duration, and Awk to perform the overall parsing,

```
#!/bin/sh

input_file="chapters.txt"
output_file="chapters.ffmetadata"

awk -F= -v duration=$(ffprobe -v error \
        -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=duration \
        -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 \
       input_video.mp4) '
  function chapter(start, end, title) {
    print "[CHAPTER]"
    print "TIMEBASE=1/1000"
    print "START=" start "000"
    print "END=" end "000"
    print "title=" title }
  BEGIN { print ";FFMETADATA1" }
  { split($1, hms, ":") ;
      end=3600 * hms[1] + 60 * hms[2] + hms[3] }
  title { chapter(start, end, title) }
  { start=end; title=$2 }
  END { chapter(start, duration, title) }' "$input_file" > "$output_file"

ffmpeg -i input_video.mp4 -i "$output_file" -map_metadata 1 -c:v copy -c:a copy -y output_video.mp4
```

Nothing here uses Bash features, so I used a `/bin/sh` shebang.

Properly speaking, you probably want to make the input video and output video file names into command-line arguments.

If you are unfamiliar with Awk, learning enough to write a script like this should not take long. A basic one-hour tutorial will already be quite sufficient, and pay back handsomely if you need to solve other problems like this.

Demo of the Awk part: https://ideone.com/scXWNJ

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to edit the assignments of START and END times in your script.

Check this out:

```
#!/bin/bash

input_file="chapters.txt"
output_file="chapters.ffmetadata"

# Create the FFmetadata chapter file
echo ";FFMETADATA1" > "$output_file"

previous_seconds=0

while IFS="=" read -r timestamp chapter_name; do
    # Convert start time to seconds
    seconds=$(date -u -d "1970-01-01 $timestamp" +"%s")
    
    echo "[CHAPTER]" >> "$output_file"
    echo "TIMEBASE=1/1000" >> "$output_file"
    echo "START=${previous_seconds}000" >> "$output_file"
    echo "END=${seconds}000" >> "$output_file"
    echo "title=$chapter_name" >> "$output_file"
    
    # Update previous_seconds for the next iteration
    previous_seconds=$seconds
done < "$input_file"

# Calculate the end time for the last chapter (duration of the video)
duration=$(ffprobe -v error -show_entries format=duration -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 input_video.mp4)
echo "[CHAPTER]" >> "$output_file"
echo "TIMEBASE=1/1000" >> "$output_file"
echo "START=${previous_seconds}000" >> "$output_file"
echo "END=${duration%.*}000" >> "$output_file"
echo "title=" >> "$output_file"

echo "Chapter file '$output_file' created successfully."

# Run FFmpeg to add chapters to the video
ffmpeg -i input_video.mp4 -i chapters.ffmetadata -map_metadata 1 -c:v copy -c:a copy -y output_video.mp4
```

**Update**

Let me change the approach and use the `awk` command to parse the timestamp and calculate the start and end times in seconds.

```
#!/bin/bash

input_file="chapters.txt"
output_file="chapters.ffmetadata"

# Create the FFmetadata chapter file
echo ";FFMETADATA1" > "$output_file"

previous_seconds=0

while IFS="=" read -r timestamp chapter_name; do
    # Parse the timestamp and calculate start and end times in seconds
    start_seconds=$(echo "$timestamp" | awk -F: '{ print ($1 * 3600) + ($2 * 60) + $3 }')
    end_seconds=$previous_seconds

    # Update previous_seconds for the next iteration
    previous_seconds=$start_seconds

    echo "[CHAPTER]" >> "$output_file"
    echo "TIMEBASE=1/1000" >> "$output_file"
    echo "START=${end_seconds}000" >> "$output_file"
    echo "END=${start_seconds}000" >> "$output_file"
    echo "title=$chapter_name" >> "$output_file"
done < "$input_file"

echo "Chapter file '$output_file' created successfully."

# Run FFmpeg to add chapters to the video
ffmpeg -i input_video.mp4 -i chapters.ffmetadata -map_metadata 1 -c:v copy -c:a copy -y output_video.mp4
```

Comment: Thanks!  This really helped, but it's shifted the chapters down by one timecode.  I update the question above to show what it's doing.

Comment: I made those changes in a new file to make sure.  Now I get an error `Chapter end time 0 before start 199000
chapters.ffmetadata: Cannot allocate memory`  I added the update 2 to the question.  The chapters.ffmetadata START= and END= seems to be doing strange things.

Comment: same error `Chapter end time 0 before start 199000
chapters.ffmetadata: Cannot allocate memory` but the chapters.ffmetadata file did change I placed the change under update 3 in the question.